# Firebase : Removing chat conversation + messages from one side

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am making a chatting application. Here is my Structure for storing messages and chats conversation.

```
"messages":{
  "ChatKey1":{
       "msg1":{
          "content":"hello",
          "timeStamp":"123344",
          "223232334sdsd":"false",
           "ssfdsfsfdsfsdf":"false"
    },
    "msg2":{
        "content":"Hi",
        "timeStamp":"123344",
        "ssfdsfsfdsfsdf":"false",
         "223232334sdsd":"false"
    }
}
"Chats_Conversation":{
    "UserID":{
    "ChatKey1":{
        "senderId":"223232334sdsd",
        "receiverID":"ssfdsfsfdsfsdf",
        "lastMessage":"hi"
    }
}
```

Where 223232334sdsd is sender ID and ssfdsfsfdsfsdf is receiver ID. Both are listetning to chatKeys1 in messages. Now i want to remove msges from sender side ? If i delete message . It will removed from both sides? I m confused. Could some one help me here please. How could i remove messages from one side

Comment: You dont have to delete  it. you store whatever it comes and skip to update the view if he only sent the message. I think you even need his own messages from FCM to confirm that the messsage has sent from his side

Comment: Did you mean to say like this to skip messages..  query.orderByChild("timeStamp").startAt("timeStamp").limitToLast(500).addValueEventListener(new)   Where timeStamp is that from where i want to show the messages

Comment: You can remove the reference to the sender in the message so that it will only apply to the receiver.

Comment: @LalitBagga Did you find an answer for this? Because yeah, if the conversation is accessed by both sides, deleting it will delete entire collection...

Comment: Has anyone found a solution on that?

Answer (score 0):

I would add 2 boolean fields, one for isDeletedReceiver, and another for isDeletedSender, then run a logical if else checks, assuming sender is opting for deletion, I'll check if its deleted for receiver, and if its true, I'll delete it entirely from the DB, and if its false, I'll display a text like 'this message is deleted' rather than the original data, and if the check returns a true value for isDeletedReceiver, I'll delete the document entirely from the DB, as no one will be needing it. So in all, you just have to play with toggling to true if deleted.